# Why is onSessionStart() not run before onRequestStart()?

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Assume the following site architecture:

```
/Application.cfc
/index.cfm
/sub/Application.cfc
/sub/index.cfm
/login/index.cfm
```

Now, here's some really basic pseudo-code:

/Application.cfc:

```
<cffunction name="onSessionStart" returntype="Void" output="false">
    <cfscript>
        SESSION.IsLoggedIn = false;

        return;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="Boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true">

    <cfscript>
        if  (SESSION.IsLoggedIn)
            REQUEST.Cart = {};
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

/sub/Application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="Boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true">

    <cfscript>
        SUPER.onRequestStart(ARGUMENTS.targetpage);
    </cfscript>

    <cfif NOT SESSION.IsLoggedIn>
        <cflocation url="/login/" addtoken="false" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

When I request /sub/index.cfm, I get the following exception: `Element ISLOGGEDIN is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.`

On my local development machine, I have Debugging Information turned on, so I can see that the SESSION is initialized, at least from a cookie standpoint, but, as you can see, my SESSION variables is NOT initialized:

```
Session Variables:
cfid=149415
cftoken=b7740eb6d2219f83-619FF01B-78AC-C0A4-1997EC503DA43982
sessionid=PRUDENTIAL_2UA1130DBK_2_149415_b7740eb6d2219f83-619FF01B-78AC-C0A4-1997EC503DA43982
urltoken=CFID=149415&CFTOKEN=b7740eb6d2219f83-619FF01B-78AC-C0A4-1997EC503DA43982
```

I cannot understand why onRequestStart() is being called before onSessionStart(). Shouldn't onSessionStart() be called first?

Comment: I think you may be looking in the wrong place - based on the information you have provided. The error message states that `USER` is undefined, yet, there is nothing in your code that uses/sets that variable. Either you need to provide more code, or the problem is not with the execution order of `onSessionStart` and `onRequestStart`. Side note - why do you drop to `cfscript` to make a simple function call? It looks messy. Either go script all the way, or stay tag based all the way, don't mix them.

Comment: It seems that you think your session variables should be in plain text in the cookies.  If that is the case, they are not.  They are stored in the memory on the server.

Comment: Just to add...I was doing some reset functionality on the event loaders (in CF9 very similar situation).  What I found is that if I killed the application scope and the session scope within the onRequestStart and then routed to onSessionStart inside of the onRequestStart I got no session.cfid or session.cftoken variables set. Which seemed odd. The reason I noticed this is because I wanted to set my client variables to match my session variables so the cookie.cfid and cookie.cftoken would fail to set because I could not do a force reset on sessions vars (didn't get the results I expected).

Comment: It is not odd, it is working as expected. Think of `OnSessionStart()` as a `listener`. Calling `onSessionStart()` does not create a new session. On the contrary, it is only called when a new session is created - or if you call it manually. Another example, if, in JavaScript, you add a 'click' handler to a button that fires a JS function, calling that same function 'manually' in another bit of JavaScript does not mean you also 'clicked' the button.

Comment: @ScottStroz, I apologize, but the error message is being generated when using my real code, not the pseudo code. I have fixed it to match the pseudo code.

Comment: @SeanCoyne, no, I am not expecting my session variables to be in plain text in the cookies. I have copied the entire SESSION scope as displayed in my debugging information on the page. Normally, all SESSION variables are included there, but in this case, only the cookie information is.

Comment: @ScottStroz, yes, I understand that onSessionStart() does not create a new session. My question is, why isn't the Session being initialized or "started" before the request begins? That seems logical, doesn't it?

Comment: Is that the actual error message that you are getting? I ask because it does not state that the variable is undefined in the session as you are assuming. Those errors will look like `Element ISLOGGEDIN is undefined in SESSION`.

Comment: If you want to know for sure which function runs first, write an app that outputs "session started" in onSessionStart() and "request started" in onRequestStart().  The index page output "Hello World", or something equally simple.  Run the index page and see what's on it.

Comment: @EricBelair sorry..my last comment was directed as Frank Tudor. His last comment seemed to imply that he thought calling `onSessionStart` would create a new session. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EricBelair - On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: @ScottStroz the error occurs in onRequestStart() in the root Application.cfc: if  (SESSION.IsLoggedIn)